# storing the output of ls command in a shell variable

Tags: linux, shell, command-substitution

I am using below command to find a most recent file with name "candump"

```
ls *.log | grep "candump" | tail -n 1
```

The output is "candump-2018-04-19_131908.log"

I want to store the output filename to a variable in my shell script. I am using the below commands:

```
logfile = `ls *.log | grep "candump" | tail -n 1`
```

and

```
logfile = $(ls *.log | grep "candump" | tail -n 1)
```

However, both times I am getting the same error, "logfile: command not found". Am I doing something wrong? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: A little search goes a long way. Possible duplicate of [How to set a variable to the output from a command in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4651437/608639), [How can I assign the output of a command to a shell variable?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/16024/56041), [Storing output of command in shell variable](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/4569/56041), etc.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to stick the variable name and its value (no space before and after the `=`).

Try :

```
logfile=$(ls *.log | grep "candump" | tail -n 1)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, was a silly mistake on my part.

Answer (score 0):

**This is working for me.**

```
#!/bin/bash 

my_command='ls | grep server.js | wc -l';

my_data=$(eval "$my_command");

echo "value in echo is:" $my_data;

if [ $my_data == "1" ]; then
    echo "value is equal to 1";
else
    echo "value is not equal to 1";
fi
```